# Clojure lazy-seq Natural Numbers

Tags: clojure

A popular online tutorial gives this example to build natural numbers:

`(def infseq (map inc (iterate inc 0)))`

For instance, `(take 5 infseq)` gives:

`1 2 3 4 5`

I can see what `(iterate inc 0)` does, but, as a whole, I do not understand what exactly is going on. (For example, this is not a normal function definition.)

Could somebody please explain?

Comment: Indeed, that is not a function definition at all: `(ifn? infseq)` returns `false`. Could you give more details on what exactly you don't understand? Is it the `map inc` part, or the `def infseq` part, or the `take 5` part? Or some combination of those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break that expression down:

```
(map inc (iterate inc 0)))
```

Is a list (the datastructure) with this structure:

```
(function-to-call function-passed-as-first-srgument another-list-as-second-arg)
```

Now let's explore it by examining it from the inside out!
That inner list:

```
(iterate inc 0)
```

has this strucute

```
(function-to-call function-passed-as-first-argument number)
```

- the function being called is `iterate`, which creates infinite sequences by keeping track of it's internal state, and every time a new value is required to make the make the sequence longer, it takes the function passed as the first argument and calls it on the current state.
- the function passed as the first argument is `inc` which takes a numbr and ads one
- the third argument to `iterate` is the initial-state. where it should start.

so when this inner expression is evaluated it will immediately return a data structure representing a list without actually building that list yet. When the first value is read from that list it will return the initial value `0` , when the second value is asked for it will use the `inc` function to come up with the number `1`. If the first or second values are needed again they will just be used as is, not recalculated.

so the first argument represents a contract to produce as many numbers as are required. This is in it's self the third argument to the original expression.

The initial expression takes that lazy list and makes a new lazy list.

this new lazy list is returned by the `map` function.

```
(map inc (0 1 2 3 4 ... as many as you read ...))
```

which will apply `inc` to each of these just as it's read, and only at  the moment it's read (actually it caches 20 or so items ahead to be a little faster) resulting in this sequence:

```
((inc 0) (inc 1) (inc 2) (inc 3) ... as much as you read from the sequence ...)
```

Which works out to:

```
(1 2 3 4 ... created lazily)
```

Which is the same result as these equivalent expressions,

```
(rest (range))

(iterate inc 1)
```

and many other forms.

Comment: Thanks. Now I see why I was confused. The author made the issue unnecessarily longer when `(def infseq (iterate inc 1))` would suffice. I thought `map` was actually needed. (It is needed if starting from `inc 0`.) And my second confusion was I was (don't know why, perhaps I am just new to the concept) thinking in terms of function definition instead of macro definition.

Answer (score 2):

. *For the purposes of the example*, we could define `map` and `iterate` as follows:

```
(defn iterate [f init]
  (lazy-cons init (iterate f (f init))))

(defn map [f [x & xs]]
  (lazy-cons (f x) (map f xs)))
```

... where `lazy-cons` is a version of `cons` that doesn't act until it has to. It used to be part of `clojure.core`, and might have been defined thus:

```
(defmacro lazy-cons [x xs]
  `(lazy-seq (cons ~x ~xs)))
```

To understand these definitions, you'll need to get to grips with recursion, laziness, destructuring, and macros: quite a task! But do so and you'll *really* understand how clojure's sequence library, including `iterate` and `map`, works. It's how I learned.

---

The definition of `iterate` is valid. The one of `map` only works for a single endless sequence argument.

Answer (score 1):

```
(take 5 (iterate inc 0)) => (0 1 2 3 4)
```

`iterate` repeatedly applys the inc function in a loop. You are starting with `0`, so you get [0 1 2 3...]

```
(take 5 (map inc (iterate inc 0))) => (1 2 3 4 5)
```

`(map inc <collection>)` applies `inc` once time to each item in the collection, to the previous result is transformed to [1 2 3 4 ...]

```
(take 5 (range)) => (0 1 2 3 4)
```

`range` w/o any args starts at 0 and counts forever, same as the first example.

Since all of these collections are infinite in length, we need something like `(take 5 <collection>)` to limit the length of what is printed.

Comment: I still do not understand. (Something to do with me, no doubt.) (Even though I already know what you said in your explanation.)